# I am trying to Implement a function which takes array input and gives products of array with skipping 0 in Javascript but I can only use .reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

```
function multiplyArray(array) {
  let product_arr = array.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
    return accumulator * currentValue
  }, 1);
  return product_arr;
}
```

Comment: You should add your input, and expected output to your question. Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Sounds like school work to me!

Comment: `return array.reduce((a,v)=>(v||1)*a,1);`

Comment: (You also haven't actually _asked_ a question.)

Answer (score 1):

You can check for `0` and return the value on the basis of that like below:

```js
function multiplyArray(array) {

  let product_arr = array.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
      // If value is 0 return accumulator else return value * accumulator
    return (currentValue == 0 ? accumulator * 1 : accumulator * currentValue)
  }, 1);

  return product_arr

}

console.log(multiplyArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 9]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just default to `1` when the array item is `0`.

```js
const multiply = (nums) => nums.reduce((a, b) => a * (b || 1), 1);

console.log(
  multiply([0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0]),
)
```